# Extending JQuery DatePicker for dblclick event and get the class of clicked/selected date (td)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Wondering how can implement following two functionalities for jquery-ui datepicker:

1- dblclick event handling,

2- Get the class(s) of the selected or clicked day (td) within the corresponding event handlers or for dbclick event handler.

here is the script which shows what I want to do: http://jsfiddle.net/ozduck/DU3h3/29/

```
enter code here
```

Comment: please share your html or jsfiddle.

Comment: Why are you attaching your datepicker to div tag.  it should be to input.

Comment: @pramod.nikam.dev: this is to make it inline